# How to programmatically check if Mac is connected to Wi-Fi network?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm able to check if my Mac is connected to Internet using Reachability, but I don't understand how to specifically check Wi-Fi connection. Any tips or Swift/Objective-C code are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to determine here? Keep in mind that some computers may have a stable Internet connection without wireless being active, e.g. through wired Ethernet.

Comment: @duskwuff I'm trying to determine whether device is connected to Wi-Fi network. Yeah, I know, I'm able to check Internet connection, no matter how device is connected to the Internet, Wi-Fi or Ethernet, what I need is to determine only Wi-Fi connection

Comment: @TarasParkhomenko, I believe what duskwuff is asking is what specifically about the wi-fi connection are you wanting to check? Be more specific, and include any examples of what you've tried.

Comment: @l'L'l The fact of connection? To understand what I want to do you only need to read the title. I'm sorry for lack of examples, but I doubt that what I've written is useful.

Comment: @TarasParkhomenko, A device or machine can be connected to a Wi-Fi network in obviously more ways than you realize, but that's not relevant apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code checks if the computer is connected to a wireless network.

**It does not check if the wireless network is connected to the internet**

```
import CoreWLAN

func isWIFIActive() -> Bool {
  let interfaceNames = CWInterface.interfaceNames()
  for interfaceName in Array(interfaceNames) {
    let interface = CWInterface(name: interfaceName as! String)
    if interface.ssid() != nil {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}


isWIFIActive()
```

`CWInterface(name:_)` is deprecated in 10.10 but still works

**Edit Dec 2017:**

A `CWWiFiClient`based one-line solution for 10.10+:

```
func isWIFIActive() -> Bool {
    return CWWiFiClient.interfaceNames()?.contains{ CWWiFiClient.shared().interface(withName: $0)?.ssid() != nil } ?? false
}
```

Comment: deprecated means "might stop working in the future". The appropriate new API `CWWiFiClient` is introduced in 10.10, `CWInterface` works in 10.6 and later

Comment: The OP writes  "Any tips or **Swift** /Objective-C code are appreciated"

Comment: I don't know the system version of the OP, so I provided a solution which works on all versions (supporting CoreWLAN)

Comment: Hmmm... I guess for some folks it doesn't matter :S

Answer (score 0):

[vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) answer without deprecations:

```
func isWIFIActive() -> Bool {
    guard let interfaceNames = CWWiFiClient.interfaceNames() else {
        return false
    }

    for interfaceName in interfaceNames {
        let interface = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface(withName: interfaceName)

        if interface?.ssid() != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```